# Objective-C NSMutableAttributedString text4 font is not showing correct font

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

I am trying to change font size, but there something wrong with my code? I can able to set font size of text1 to text3 but text4 isn't able to work and doesn't change font size to 16.
text1 text2 text3 text4

```
NSString *String1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\%@\n%@\%@",text1,text2,text3,text4];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:String1];
NSDictionary <NSAttributedStringKey, id> *attributes0 = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:fonts size:10]};
[attributedText addAttributes:attributes0 range:[String1 rangeOfString:text1]];
NSDictionary <NSAttributedStringKey, id> *attributes2 = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:fonts size:12]};        
[attributedText addAttributes:attributes2 range:[String1 rangeOfString:text2]];
NSDictionary <NSAttributedStringKey, id> *attributes4 = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:fonts size:14]};
[attributedText addAttributes:attributes4 range:[String1 rangeOfString:text3]];
NSDictionary <NSAttributedStringKey, id> *attributes4 = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:fonts size:16]};
[attributedText addAttributes:attributes4 range:[String1 rangeOfString:text4]];
```

text1 text2 text3 text4(font size is not working and just shows the default size of main string of * . size to 13 only)

Comment: And what returns "[String1 rangeOfString:text4]" ?

Comment: self.attributedText =attributedText;

Comment: Can you print `attributedText`? Also, are you sure that text4 is not "included"/the same as text3, or text2, or text1 ?

Comment: solved by adding appendAttributedString

Answer (score 0):

Have you try changing your variable name, it might cause confusion.

In your third attribute change `attributes4` to `attribute3`

```
NSDictionary <NSAttributedStringKey, id> *attributes3 = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:fonts size:14]};
        [attributedText addAttributes:attributes3 range:[String1 rangeOfString:text3]];
```